# What is the use of Shuffling a Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, tensor

I have a general question regarding
`tf.random.shuffle()`
What is the use of shuffling a tensor in a neural network model ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Off the top of my head, here is an example usage:

Imagine you are passing the `validation_split` parameter (or similar) to the model. *This parameter always splits the data in the same way.*

But, if your data is ordered, *e.g.* by type, then the model will only be trained on a skewed subset. *I.e.* it will become specialised to data which is not fully representative of the population.

**Thus, you could use the shuffle function to remove any orderings/biases in the subset before feeding it to the model.**

Another similar purpose could be to prevent the model from learning the order of the data instead of inferring connections between data points.